# Unable to infer SQL type for my user-defined function which return BigInt

Tags: postgresql, scala, postgresql-9.2, playframework-2.2, anorm

My code:

```
def function1(userId: Long) = DB withConnection {
  implicit con =>
    val res = SQL(
      """
      SELECT my_custom_function({userId}, {param2}) as "my_title"
      """
    ).on('userId -> userId,
      'param2 -> Array(Statuses.paid.id, Statuses.pending.id))
     .as(SqlParser.get[Option[Long]]("my_title").single) //error

    if (res.isDefined) res.get
    else 0L
}
```

`my_custom_function` return `Long` or `BigInt`.

This code throws the error [`PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of [I. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.]`

What's up with that?

Comment: I think Scala has its own BigInt, it's probably getting muddled between java.lang.BigInt and whatever the Scala one is.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is Array parameter. Latest Anorm prevent unsafe parameter conversion that can lead to such case. You can try it with an Anorm snapshot.